# entry for deploying flows using package.xml

Tags: deployment, visual-workflow, flow, package.xml

there are two metadata types named flow and flow definition. do we need both for deploying flows and process builder processes ? When i did a retrieve, for flow metadata type, i see entries like this for a flow :

```
<members>TestFlow</members>
<members>TestFlow-1</members>
<members>TestFlow-2</members>
<members>TestFlow-3</members>
```

which of these entries i need to keep while deploying in package.xml ?
Do i need to keep both entries with name TestFlow and TestFlow-3 which is the flow with most recent version ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

finally i went with this :

```
  <types>
    <members>*</members>
     <name>Flow</name>
  </types>
  <types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>FlowDefinition</name>
  </types>
```

Comment: @user15608 Converted your answer to a comment. We don't generally want thank-you comments posted as upvotes are the way to do that, but I've moved it here so you might start getting some points. Hope you fill out your profile and stick around!